Changing Data type input from MySQL in FastAPI
enter code hereI have "serialize_response" error for this line :
@app.get("/get-sensors/", response_model=List[Data])

and this :
return {"status": "success", "list": data}

how can I fix this!
I want to get data as Dictionary type
the main code is:
import mysql.connector
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from typing import Optional, List, Dict, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel
from mysql.connector import Error
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def get_db_connection():
    return mysql.connector.connect(
        user='*****',
        password='*****',
        host='*****',
        port=*****,
        database='******'
    )


class Data(BaseModel):
    timestamp: Optional[str] = None
    acceleration_x: Optional[float] = None
    acceleration_y: Optional[float] = None
    acceleration_z: Optional[float] = None
    velocity_x: Optional[float] = None
    velocity_y: Optional[float] = None
    velocity_z: Optional[float] = None
    x: Optional[float] = None
    y: Optional[float] = None
    z: Optional[float] = None
    angular_accelerltion_x: Optional[float] = None
    angular_accelerltion_y: Optional[float] = None
    angular_accelerltion_z: Optional[float] = None
    angular_velocity_x: Optional[float] = None
    angular_velocity_y: Optional[float] = None
    angular_velocity_z: Optional[float] = None
    orientation_x: Optional[float] = None
    orientation_y: Optional[float] = None
    orientation_z: Optional[float] = None
    temperature: Optional[float] = None


fibo_sub = FastAPI()


@fibo_sub.post("/insert_sensors/")
def insert_sensors(data: Data):
    db = get_db_connection()
    mycurser = db.cursor()
    insert_query = (
        "INSERT INTO sensors(timestamp,acceleration_x,acceleration_y,acceleration_z,velocity_x,velocity_y,velocity_z,x,y,z,angular_accelerltion_x,angular_accelerltion_y,angular_accelerltion_z,angular_velocity_x,angular_velocity_y,angular_velocity_z,orientation_x,orientation_y,orientation_z,temperature) "
        " VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
    )
    vals = (data.timestamp, data.acceleration_x, data.acceleration_y, data.acceleration_z, data.velocity_x, data.velocity_y, data.velocity_z, data.x, data.y, data.z, data.angular_accelerltion_x,
            data.angular_accelerltion_y, data.angular_accelerltion_z, data.angular_velocity_x, data.angular_velocity_y, data.angular_velocity_z, data.orientation_x, data.orientation_y, data.orientation_z, data.temperature)
    mycurser.execute(insert_query, vals)
    db.commit()
    return {"status": "success"}


@fibo_sub.get("/get-sensors/", response_model=List[Data])
def get_sensors(start_date: str):
    db = get_db_connection()
    mycurser = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_time = start_time - timedelta(seconds=60)
    print(start_time, end_time)

    insert_query = "SELECT * FROM sensors WHERE timestamp BETWEEN %s AND %s"
    mycurser.execute(insert_query, (end_time, start_time))

    data = mycurser.fetchall()
    
    return {"status": "success", "list": data}

ERROR :
INFO:     127.0.0.1:7681 - "GET /get-sensors/?start_date=2004-09-10%2000%3A00%3A31 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 399, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 296, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Amir_encore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 155, in serialize_response
    raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 1 validation errors:
  {'type': 'list_type', 'loc': ('response',), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid list', 'input': {'status': 'success', 'list': [{'id': 8, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2004, 9, 10, 0, 0, 
1), 'acceleration_x': Decimal('12.1000'), 'acceleration_y': Decimal('2.8000'), 'acceleration_z': Decimal('23.2000'), 'velocity_x': Decimal('1.1000'), 'velocity_y': Decimal('12.1000'), 'velocity_z': Decimal('1.1000'), 'x': Decimal('1.10'), 'y': Decimal('1.20'), 'z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_velocity_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_velocity_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_velocity_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_x': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'temperature': Decimal('1.20')}, {'id': 9, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2004, 9, 10, 0, 0, 21), 'acceleration_x': Decimal('12.1000'), 'acceleration_y': Decimal('2.8000'), 'acceleration_z': Decimal('0.2000'), 'velocity_x': Decimal('1.1000'), 'velocity_y': Decimal('12.1000'), 'velocity_z': Decimal('1.1000'), 'x': Decimal('4.10'), 'y': Decimal('1.20'), 'z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_velocity_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_velocity_y': Decimal('4.20'), 'angular_velocity_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_x': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'temperature': Decimal('1.20')}, {'id': 10, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2004, 9, 10, 0, 0, 31), 'acceleration_x': Decimal('12.1000'), 'acceleration_y': Decimal('2.8000'), 'acceleration_z': Decimal('0.2000'), 'velocity_x': Decimal('1.1000'), 'velocity_y': Decimal('12.1000'), 'velocity_z': Decimal('1.1000'), 'x': Decimal('4.10'), 'y': Decimal('1.20'), 'z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_accelerltion_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'angular_velocity_x': Decimal('2.20'), 'angular_velocity_y': Decimal('4.20'), 'angular_velocity_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_x': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_y': Decimal('1.20'), 'orientation_z': Decimal('1.20'), 'temperature': Decimal('1.20')}]}}


Please, provide MRE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example). Or the example of data you want to return

The answer I gave yo below should work for you

finally
@fibo_sub.get("/get_data_in_range/")

def get_data_in_range(end_time: str):
try:
db = get_db_connection()
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    
    start_datetime = end_datetime - timedelta(seconds=60)

 
    formatted_start_time = start_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    formatted_end_time = end_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

  
    query = (
        "SELECT * FROM sensors WHERE timestamp >= %s AND timestamp <= %s"
    )
    cursor.execute(query, (formatted_start_time, formatted_end_time))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()

    if not rows:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No data found in the specified time range.")

    return rows

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(err))
except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


Notice, that if you use @fibo_sub.get("/get_data_in_range/") (you don't specify response model) then you don't have response schema in the openapi documentation, and FastAPI doesn't validate your response data (so it could lead to potential data leaking). If it's not a problem for your use case, than this approach is OK
